# Debian Jessie install Oracle JDK 1.8 on ARM

Tags: debian, jdk

I need to install Oracle JDK on my Debian Server. I have tried a lot tutorials and watch around here but I seems to be too stupid to manage it. Please could somebody give me a how to.

I have added the repo:

```
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

but getting this:

```
    # apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abh�gigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, oris only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

If you need some more information please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to notice that the quide that you are using is Ubuntu-specific, there is no guarantee that it will work on Debian.

Also, you haven't mentioned which Debian and Java versions you are going to use.

If you are going to install Oracle Java 8 on Debian 8 (Jessie), please, do the following:

1. Add a "contrib" component to /etc/apt/sources.list, for example:

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib`

2. Update the list of available packages and install the java-package package:

`# apt-get update && apt-get install java-package && exit`

3. Download the desired Java JDK/JRE binary distribution ([from Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads)) as a tar.gz file.
4. Use java-package to create a Debian package, for example:

`$ make-jpkg jdk-8u51-linux-x64.tar.gz`

5. Install the binary package created:

`$ su -`

`# dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u51_amd64.deb`.

The guide is based on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage), you may find more information there.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I getting this error: /mnt/disk/public$ make-jpkg jdk-8u121-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
Creating temporary directory: /tmp/make-jpkg.loJtPn8dUA

Detected Debian build architecture: armel
Detected Debian GNU type: arm-linux-gnueabi

No matching packaging method was found for jdk-8u121-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz.
Please make sure you are using a tar.gz or a self-extracting archive
Removing temporary directory: done

Comment: is that the wrong tar.gz file?

Comment: @fteinz I think so. Do you use ARM-based Debian?

Comment: @ IDvoretskyi Yes - uname -a Linux debianNSA325 4.4.18-kirkwood-rm-1 #1 PREEMPT Wed Aug 17 17:49:56 CEST 2016 armv5tel GNU/Linux

Comment: @fteinz please, use one for ARM from this page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: yes I have used the first one: jdk-8u121-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the scripts of java-package you can see that it does not look for the 32/64 bit identifier. Rename the part of the file containing arm32-vfp-hflt to arm-vfp-hflt.